# How can i load interstitial ad in activity and show is in another activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, interstitial

i want load interstitial ad in activity and show it in another activity . i found this topic and try to do the steps in the first answer but there are a lot errors .

[How To preload admob interstitial ad and send to another android activity using intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852032/how-to-preload-admob-interstitial-ad-and-send-to-another-android-activity-using)

That what i did :

- I created a public class and named it "AdManager" and put this code in it:

  ```
  `package com.website.test;
  import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
  ```

  public class AdManager {

  // Static fields are shared between all instances.
  static InterstitialAd ad;

  public AdManager() {
      createAd();
  }

  public void createAd() {
      // Create an ad.
      interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
      interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("");

  `AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
          .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
          .addTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE_ID).build();

  // Load the interstitial ad.
  interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
  }
  public InterstitialAd getAd() {
      return ad;}}`
- In create event of class A i put this :

`AdManager adManager = new AdManager();
adManager.createAd();`

- In create event of the activity which i want show interstitial ad i put this :

`InterstitialAd ad = admanager.getAd();
        if (ad.isLoaded) {
            ad.show();
        }`

but there are some errors as it shown in the pics i attached , please tell me what is wrong ?

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY4hL.jpg)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGBcz.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately  no one helped me :(

Answer (score 2):

```
class AdManager {
// Static fields are shared between all instances.
private static InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

private static boolean isInterAdsShowed = false;
private Activity activity;
private String AD_UNIT_ID;

AdManager(Activity activity, String AD_UNIT_ID) {

    this.activity = activity;
    this.AD_UNIT_ID = AD_UNIT_ID;
    createAd();
}

void createAd() {
    // Create an ad.
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(activity);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            //.addTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE_ID)
            .build();

    // Load the interstitial ad.
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

static InterstitialAd getAd() {
    if(interstitialAd != null && interstitialAd.isLoaded() && !isInterAdsShowed) {
        isInterAdsShowed = true;
        return interstitialAd;
    }
    else return null;
}
```

}

.....
Activity A

```
  AdManager adManager = new AdManager(this,"your ads id");
    adManager.createAd();
```

....
Activity B

```
 InterstitialAd ad = AdManager.getAd();
    if (ad != null) {
        ad.show();
    }
```

Comment: What if we want listeners as well.

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT DO THIS** You are almost certainly going to leak memory and eventually crash your app.

The errors in your images are basic Java syntax issues.

Image 1

1. interstialAd variable is not declared
2. AdRequest has not been imported
3. AD_UNIT_ID has not been declared

Image 2

1. adManager has not been declared.