# How to call Interstitial Ad in main activity and then call it in other activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, admob, android-runonuithread

I have 2 following activities - Main and GameOver.
I want to declare all ad related data in MainActivity but show the ad when a button is clicked in the GameOverActivity.

I have tried this: [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/135237/calling-admob-interstitial-ad-from-another-class)

My MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private FlyingBirdView gameView;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final static long Interval = 30;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gameView = new FlyingBirdView(this);
        setContentView(gameView);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        gameView.invalidate();
                    }
                });
            }
        },0, Interval);



    }


}

class AdManager {
    // Static fields are shared between all instances.
    private static InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    private static boolean isInterAdsShowed = false;
    private Activity activity;
    private String AD_UNIT_ID;

    AdManager(Activity activity, String AD_UNIT_ID) {

        this.activity = activity;
        this.AD_UNIT_ID = AD_UNIT_ID;
        createAd();
    }

    void createAd() {
        // Create an ad.
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(activity);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                //.addTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE_ID)
                .build();

        // Load the interstitial ad.
        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    static InterstitialAd getAd() {
        if (interstitialAd != null && interstitialAd.isLoaded() && !isInterAdsShowed) {
            isInterAdsShowed = true;
            return interstitialAd;
        } else return null;
    }
}
```

GameOverActivity:

```
    public class GameOverActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button startgameagain;
    private TextView DisplayScore;
    private String score;

    private TextView updatestext;
    private Button rateus;
    private Button share;
    //private AdView mAdView;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);



        //mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        //mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        AdManager adManager = AdManager.getInstance();
        adManager.createAd(MainActivity.this);



        share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
        rateus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rateus);
        score = getIntent().getExtras().get("score").toString();
        updatestext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updatestext);
        startgameagain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_again_btn);
        DisplayScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayScore);

        startgameagain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                AdManager adManager = AdManager.getInstance();
                InterstitialAd ad =  adManager.getAd();

                if (ad.isLoaded()) {
                    ad.show();
                }
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(GameOverActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                }



        });

        rateus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String str ="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dnyanesh.theflyingbird";
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(str)));
            }
        });

        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intentInvite = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intentInvite.setType("text/plain");
                String body = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dnyanesh.theflyingbird";
                String subject = "Checkout";
                intentInvite.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                intentInvite.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentInvite, "Share using"));
            }
        });

        DisplayScore.setText("Score: " + score);
        updatestext.setText("STAY TUNED FOR MORE UPDATES");

    }
}
```

Error in GameOverActivity is:
1> cannot resolve method getinstance().
2> MainActivity.this is not an enclosing class.

What do I do?
I just want to call the ad in GameOverActivity from MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate singleton class and then use that to initialize ads and show or hide them from any activity you want.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26852122/4406346) answer for a similar approach.

You should never access functions of another activity like this: `MainActivity.ShowAd();` Your present approach will lead to several memory leaks.

Comment: Hello,
Can you help with the updated question please

Comment: From the link u gave i tried with singleton code but it says internstatial ad cannot be resolved. So i followed other admanager example but that is also not working.

Comment: Make sure you have added correct libraries in the gradle file and correct imports for Ads in your java file.